# What does a query on UNIQUE INDEX return when it encounters a duplicate?

Tags: android, sqlite, unique-index

I have a database table called Details, there are three columns of interest to me here:

`| _id | Name | DOB | ......| .....`

I create a Unique index on the above - I want no two rows with the same Name and Birthdate:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX _id ON Details (Name, BirthDate);
```

Now my problem scenario is as follows: 
I am reading from a file - inside a for loop - for each line in the file I am inserting a record into the above table if my insert query finds a duplicate, what does it return? I want to stop the iteration of the for loop to skip the insert statements after I find a duplicate and start at the next iteration. How do I detect this?

Following is my insert statement:

```
public void insert(String birthDate, String name, String daysOld, String hoursOld, String uRi, String minutesOld, String months, String seconds, String timestamP, String weeks, String years, String isAdhoc){
        //  InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(db, "columnTable");

        String INUP= "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Details (BirthDate, Name, isAdhoc, daysOld, hoursOld, imageUri, minutesOld, monthsOld, secondsOld, timestamp, weeksOld, yearsOld) " +
                "values ("+"'"+birthDate+"'"+","+"'"+name+"'"+","+"'"+isAdhoc+"'"+","+"'"+daysOld+"'"+","+"'"+ hoursOld+"'"+","+"'"+ uRi+"'"+","+"'"+minutesOld+"'"+","+"'"+ months+"'"+","+"'"+ seconds+"'"+","+"'"+timestamP+"'"+","+"'"+weeks+"'"+","+"'"+years+"'"+");";  
        mDb.execSQL(INUP);
    }
```

Comment: Show us your java code. When you execute a SQL command, you should check returned value.

Comment: Thank you, what part of my java code do you want to check? The insert statements? The code is too huge I can however reproduce related snippets.

Comment: Insert statement may be enough.

Comment: I have update the above, please refresh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `INSERT OR REPLACE`. Duplicate entries will replace existing ones, so no duplicates will exist and no error will happen.

You may use just `INSERT` or `INSERT OR IGNORE`, if you don't want existing entries to be replaced.

[execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) reference strongly encourages - and is a good practice for many reasons - to use [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) instead.

Comment: What if I dont want to insert if I find a record with same name and Birth date? Should I change the INSERT OR REPLACE to just INSERT? Also if I do that and I encounter a duplicate what return type should I check for? I want to skip the iteration of my loop and start at the next iteration.